# @SqlDelete is not working for soft deletion in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have one table called AdminRole

> ADMIN_ROLE_ID | DESCRIPTION | NAME | ARCHIVED

I need to delete a record from `AdminRole` as admin role is very important. I need to perform soft deletion instead of hard deletion. For this I am trying to use `@SqlDelete` hibernate annotation. My entity class is this:

```
@Entity
@table(name="ADMINROLE")
@SqlDelte(sql="UPDATE ADMINROLE SET ARCHIVED = 'Y' WHERE ADMIN_ROLE_ID=?")
public class AdminRole{
@column(name="ADMIN_ROLE_ID" )
protected Lond id;
@column(name="DESCRIPTION" )
protected String description;
@column(name="NAME" )
protected String name;
...
...
}
```

I have to show the record on front end when `ARCHIVED` in `N` if it is `Y` record is not visible in front end, when I create admin role `ARCHIVED` is setting to `N` succesfully and showing on front end. But the problem is when I try to delete the `admin role` from front end the `ARCHIVED` is not setting to `Y` due to this record is showing on front end.

In DAO

```
public AdminDAO {

    protected EntityManager manager;

    public void remove(Serializable entity){
        manager.remove(entity)
    }
}
```

why is `@SqlDelete` is not working for me can anyone help me? No exception raised on log file. When this `@SqlDelete` will be executed?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by myself, problem is from my side only I accidentally updated different table now I changed it for my `adminrole` table

Before

`@SqlDelte(sql="UPDATE ROLE SET ARCHIVED = 'Y' WHERE ROLE_ID=?")`

after

`@SqlDelte(sql="UPDATE ADMINROLE SET ARCHIVED = 'Y' WHERE ADMIN_ROLE_ID=?")`

after posting this question I realized my mistake..

Answer (score 0):

I was solving also "SQLDelete not working" issue and this is first google result I get, so maybe will be helful for others:

When you are using superclass mapping, you need to specify SQLDelete for every entity which extends the superclass, not only on superclass itself, despite they are all stored in one DB table.

Comment: Can you explain this answer with possibly an example of your own(preferred) or the example in the original question.

Comment: `@Entity
@Table(name = "VEHICLE")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "TYPE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@SQLDelete(sql = "update VEHICLE set ARCHIVED = 1 where id = ? ")
abstract class Vehicle {...}`

I would expected that SQLDelete will be used for all classes which extends abstract Vehicle, because they are all in same DB table. This is not true, you have to specify SQLDelete for each sub-class, probably because Hibernate is object based, not table based.

Comment: Please edit the answer so that next viewers will be able to grasp it quickly.

Comment: Please edit the answer so that next viewers will be able to grasp it quickly. I just wanted to improve the answer since it seemed to solve the problem given in question